# Mysql trough access

Tags: mysql, ms-access

EDIT
I solved the half, that i made a pass through query, so now I only need this:

```
(Licenszek.verz_id)=[Forms]![Hasznalat]![verzio];
```

to be implemented To the pass trough, ot be the passtrough and a simple query combined. 
Basically: I have more listbox andi want that the listbox values depending on the other listboxes chosen value. I had it seperatly, but now i need to combine with the pass through that i made.

My passthrough query:

```
SELECT lic_kod, lic_db, (
SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM Hasznalat h WHERE l.lic_id = h.lic_id) AS felhasznalt
FROM Licenszek l GROUP BY lic_kod, lic_db HAVING l.lic_db > felhasznalt
```

Comment: Post it as answer and close it.

Answer (score 1):

Set the first query to pass through, it will allow Access to send the query directly to the server, then make an another query which is get it's data from the passthrough and now you can add the "Controller"